# Clearsheet VBA syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to understand code but I've got some troubles with one string:

```
  ClearSheet "ABCD", 8
```

Goggled it but found nothing about number after sheet's name.

Comment: What is `ClearSheet`? Is this some procedure you wrote? *"I've got some troubles"* Care to be more specific? What is your specific problem?

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand meaning of "8" after `ClearSheet` . And `ClearSheet` is just the command in VBA. P.S. In my own opinion question is specific enough if you read it from A to Z

Comment: Adding the relevant parts of the code you are working with would help, as it'll be impossible to tell what exactly `ClearSheet` is and what you are trying do to it in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"ABCD"` and `8` are parameters of the `ClearSheet` function.

`ClearSheet` is not a VBA command, so it must be a function defined somewhere in the code you are trying to understand.

Use the find command of your IDE, look for the `ClearSheet` string everywhere, and once you found it, look at its parameters.  Here you'll be able to understand what the second parameters does (it's the `8` value in your sample)